# How to save a single variable that can be call anywhere in the solution that is azure friendly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

At first I was passing around a session variable but then someone told me that isn't supported in azure.  Does anyone have any other suggestions ?  I'm just saving an object of a login  user.

Comment: Session is supported in Azure, but if you expect people to be bounced between different instances of the app during their time you'll need a centralized session store so that the data is available to all instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure does support sessions, just that placing sessions in individual web roles is not going to work well.  For example, if you want to scale your app to 2, 4 or 8 servers or maintain high availability you will have a load balancer that will route the requests between the different servers.  Therefore, if you have multiple web servers each with their own user sessions behind a load balancer...you will have a problem as you could have a request that goes to a web role (server) without the session state data.

If you want to store a single variable that is available to all web roles...

- Distributed Caching (Azure has a couple options for this)
- Azure Table Storage (it would be fast for a single variable)
- SQL Azure DB (probably overkill for a single variable)

All of these options above would allow shared access (read/write) from multiple Azure web roles.  There are ASP.NET session state providers written for Azure Caching and SQL Azure DB that are available too.  Conversely, Azure Table Storage is a real good option for very fast retrieval of data based on a unique key.

Answer (score 0):

If your web role is running on single instance then sessions will work fine.
but in case of scalability needs,you will have to go for caching.